# Use section headers on SwiftUI Picker list?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

I'm trying to get something similar to the following using SwiftUI and `Picker()`
[image]

But when I try to use `Section(header: )` I get the following:

[image]

```
Form {
    Picker("S", selection: $sensor) {
        Section(header: Text("This should be a header")) {
           Text("This is the content")
            Text("This is more content")
        }
        
        Section(header: Text("Another header")) {
           Text("This is the content 2")
            Text("This is more content 2")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is one `Picker`. I think that is two Pickers with maybe one selection variable.

In Xcode 13 you can use Inline Picker Style to create the inset look

```
import SwiftUI
struct PickerModel: Identifiable{
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var parent: String
    var children: [String]
}

var pickers: [PickerModel]{
    [PickerModel(parent: "Child 1-B", children: ["Child 1-A","Child 1-B","Child 1-C"]),
     PickerModel(parent: "Parent 2", children: ["Child 1-A","Child 1-B","Child 1-C","Child 1-D"])
    ]
}
struct MultiplePickerView: View {
    @State var sensor: String = "no sensor selected"
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Text(sensor)
            ForEach(pickers){picker in
                Section(header: Text(picker.parent)){
                    Picker("", selection: $sensor){
                        ForEach(picker.children, id:\.description){child in
                            Text(child)
                                //Make sure tag is unique across pickers
                                .tag("\(picker.parent)  \(child)")
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
                        .labelsHidden()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in Xcode 12 you have to create the picker functionality manually

```
struct MultiplePickerView: View {
    @State var sensor: String = "no sensor selected"
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Text(sensor)
            ForEach(pickers){picker in
                Section(header: Text(picker.parent)){
                        ForEach(picker.children, id:\.description){child in
                            //tag must be unique throughout the pickers
                            let tag = "\(picker.parent)  \(child)"
                            HStack{
                                Text(child)
                                Spacer()
                                
                                if sensor == tag{
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark").foregroundColor(.blue)
                                }
                            }
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                sensor = tag
                            }
                            
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

it

Comment: Hmm, how are you getting the pickers to look like that? Mine are as wheels when using that code.

Comment: With the picker style just below the tag. If you copy and paste the code you should get it working right away

Comment: Yeah, I have exactly the code you have there but when I try it in Xcode, the pickers come out as wheels... otherwise it's working properly. I want the pickers to have the same styling as `InsetGroupedListStyle()` which is what your screenshot is showing.

Comment: Paste my code in an empty project you’ll see maybe you have something g overriding the style

Comment: Just tested on a fresh app, same thing. Maybe you're on a different Swift/iOS version than me? I'm targetting iOS 14 right now.

Comment: I’m out right now so I can’t double check but in-line picker style is available in iOS 14 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/inlinepickerstyle

Comment: It seems to be Xcode 12 vs 13. In Xcode 12 `Inline` does not work in a `Form` but will in a `List` so to duplicate the look you would have to create it manually and implement the picker functionality yourself. I added the sample code.